# Dimensions and extent changed after rast from 'xyz' data.frame

Tags: raster, r, terra

```
s                                  #oringinal raster
s                                  #check dimensions and extent
df <- s %>% as.data.frame(xy=T)    #convert to df

t <- rast(df,type='xyz')           #convert to spatraster back
t                                  #check dimensions and extent
```

I have a oringinal raster called 's', and its nrows and ncols are 1510,1516.
But after I convert it to data.frame, and convert data.frame back to raster, its nrows and ncols are 1495, 1652.

Why it changed?

```
> s
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 1510, 1656, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 250, 250  (x, y)
extent      : 79018.05, 493018.1, 4079976, 4457476  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : WGS 84 / UTM zone 49N (EPSG:32649) 
source      : memory 
name        :   sosslope 
min value   : -6.8730011 
max value   : -0.2319214 
> t
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 1495, 1652, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 250, 250  (x, y)
extent      : 79768.05, 492768.1, 4081976, 4455726  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. :  
source      : memory 
name        :   sosslope 
min value   : -6.8730011 
max value   : -0.2319214
```

Comment: the dimension numbers in your text ("1510,1516" and "1495, 1652") don't match the numbers in the printouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as.data.frame(xy=T)` will remove cells that are `NA`. If you have outer rows or columns that are all `NA`, these will be trimmed off, resulting in a smaller raster on re-conversion. Use `na.rm=FALSE` in `as.data.frame` to return all points in the data frame.

Example, a small 3x4 raster of 1:12 values:

```
> s = rast(matrix(1:12,3,4))
> d = as.data.frame(s, xy=TRUE)
```

`d` is 12 rows as expected:

```
> dim(d)
[1] 12  3
```

convert to raster, get a 3x4 raster back:

```
> r = rast(d,type='xyz')
> dim(r)
[1] 3 4 1
```

Now try again with `NA` in the middle of the raster:

```
> s[2,2] = NA
> d = as.data.frame(s, xy=TRUE)
```

returns 11 points:

```
> dim(d)
[1] 11  3
```

but the resulting raster is still 3x4:

```
> r = rast(d,type='xyz')
> dim(r)
[1] 3 4 1
```

set the whole of the first column to `NA`:

```
> s[,1] = NA
> d = as.data.frame(s, xy=TRUE)
> r = rast(d,type='xyz')
```

And the result is now only 3x3:

```
> dim(r)
[1] 3 3 1
```

Use `na.rm=FALSE` (and you shouldn't use `T` and `F` for `TRUE` and `FALSE`):

```
> d = as.data.frame(s, xy=TRUE, na.rm=FALSE)
> dim(d)
[1] 12  3
```

That data frame retained the `NA` values, and they are included when reconstructing:

```
> r = rast(d,type='xyz')
> dim(r)
[1] 3 4 1
```

Giving back the original 3x4 raster.

I suspect this is what is happening with your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But why shouldn't use ''T'' and ''F'' for ''TRUE'' and ''FALSE''? I try to test them, the results are same.

Comment: Because `T` and `F` can be changed - try `F=(1==1)` - but `TRUE` and `FALSE` can't - try `FALSE=(1==1)`. 99.9% of the time you'll get away with it but...